# Can I crosspost to Stack Overflow a question that was barely seen on DBA?

Tags: discussion, cross-posting

I posted this last night: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77243/connected-to-an-idle-instance-trouble-creating-db and it only got 13 views. I am worried frankly that no-one saw it, an issue that would not concern me on Stack Overflow. I think the question fits either site.

Comment: ...maybe we should make it easier for users to migrate their own questions?  Maybe just once per question, to prevent abuse?  Just a random thought prompted by this question.

Comment: My two cents (i.e. I only read your question diagonally): *Environment: blah blah* is not engaging from the get-go, your title does not reflect enough of your specific problem vs. generic admin trouble, and we have to read too much of your question to get to the point. I would suggest you restructure it with your *I tried to connect to my database and got `Connected to an idle instance`* paragraph as a lead. That edit alone will bump your question back to the dba.se main page, so it may gather a wider audience.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Users can already migrate their own questions. If they have no upvoted or accepted answers, you can delete your own question and repost it somewhere else.

Comment: That's a good suggestion @FrédéricHamidi. I will do that once I get back to my PC.

Comment: @BilltheLizard, That's actually pretty counter intuitive.

Comment: @BilltheLizard, Are there consequences of doing that? I've heard that the system would boot you out if you do too many self-deletes. Is that true?

Comment: @Pacerier You are limited to deleting 5 posts per day, so you're rate limited that way. Low-reputation users do want to watch how many posts they delete, as that can lead to a ban from asking/answering more questions. You do get a warning before the ban is applied, though. Also, at 20k rep you don't have to worry much about this. I don't know how many posts you'd have to delete to get near a ban, but I know it's a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is probably off topic for Stack Overflow, DBA seems to be the perfect place for it.

You would be better off promoting the question in other places (G+, other DB forums, etc.) where the appropriate people would see it. You might also want to consider adding a bounty.

Comment: OK, I will be satisfied with this answer for now. I re-structured the post, I put it on an Oracle forum and will promote it on G+ too. Fingers crossed for me. :)

Answer (score 3):

The short answer [is NO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069), you shouldn't post the same question on multiple SE sites simultaneously. As suggested in the comments though, you can certainly delete your question from one site and repost on another **if** it's still on topic and there are no upvoted or accepted answers.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure why this got a downvote. [Here is a post from Jeff Attwood himself](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64073) where he says we should not post on multiple sites simultaneously. Am I misunderstanding something?