# Is it OK to duplicate question across sites to get larger attention?

Tags: discussion, migrated-questions, cross-posting

As I remember I've seen some questions saying it is migrated. I know a question gets migrated when it is closed as off-topic but it could be fit on another Stack Exchange site.

Obviously only moderators can migrate (if the question is not older than 60 days), and it would be a mistake to flag questions for migration to get larger attention.

For example: I have [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/90833/unreal-engine-4-blank-material) question on *gamedev.se*. (Let's just say this question belongs to both Gamedev and SO.) I know Stack Overflow is about programming and if you won't give any code in your questions you can probably count on those downvotes but both sites offer the tag *[unreal-4](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unreal-4)/[unreal-engine4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unreal-engine4)*. Same tag.

*NOTE: Checked the questions in the unreal-4 tag on SO and 75% of the questions has no code in it.*

1. How about having a question that would fit on 2 or more sites in the network? Simply would you just ask it on those sites or is there something you could do?
2. Is it OK to ask this question on more than 1 network site to get larger attention?

Comment: I think *ideally* you should only ask it in the site that has the most relevance to the question. For example, if the question is about game development in general, ask it there. If it, in the other hand, is about an *specific* bug/issue with code, post it on SO.

Comment: @JCOC611 How about a question meets both of your 'requirements'?

Comment: I'm not saying that *can't* happen, but, for example the question you linked to doesn't appear to be quite as relevant to SO as it is to gamedev, given that it is caused by a game development tool, rather than a piece of code. But you could definitely make the argument for a theoretical question that fit two or more sites, in which case I guess you should *only* resort to other sites *if* an initial site proved futile in answering the question.

Comment: I'd point you to [Can cross-posts actually be valuable to two communities, with the exception of being worded identically?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243801/213963) and [my answer there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243851/213963).  There's also [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/213963) and all its [linked questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/64068?lq=1).

Comment: @MichaelT wow, didn't find these, thanks, probably I'll delete this cause of possible duplicate.

Comment: @balintpekker leave it here - those were all from meta. *Stack**Exchange*** rather than Overflow.

Comment: See also [Can I post the same question on Stack Overflow and GameDev?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275028), [Can I crosspost to Stack Overflow a question that was barely seen on DBA?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271906)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The consensus for this tends to be a resounding "No".  The most authoritative question on Meta.SE is [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/213963)

The key point to understanding this is in a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu#comment181805_75012):

> this can be OK, so long as the question is tailored to each audience on the different sites and is *materially different* in each case. Just to be 100% clear, copy-pasting a question across sites with no changes is considered abusive behavor. - Jeff Atwood♦ Jan 15 '11 at 3:51

Building more on this, when you post to two or more sites, you are going to get multiple answers.  The information for where someone should look when coming from google is now scattered across multiple sites. To an extent, this is what Stack Exchange was founded to try to prevent - a single repository of knowledge on a topic (rather than going to a dozen forums).

It also wastes some of the time for people who are answering. Say you got an answer on one site.  The other site still shows this as unanswered even though you've got your answer elsewhere on Stack Exchange. That other person is spending time and effort to answer something that has already been answered.

If there are issues of clarification or content, it means that twice the amount of work is spent fixing up the question.

Specifically addressing the audience, the audience will be there no matter where you ask it. It is more likely to annoy the audience (in wasting their time) when they see multiple copies of the same question posted on multiple sites. People active on GameDev.SE are also likely active on Stack Overflow and the experts on the subject you are interested in are watching the tags on both sites. You may miss a few people here and there - but the audience that you are after is in both places - so pick the one that will give you the answer tailored to how you want it answered.

See also:

- [Can cross-posts actually be valuable to two communities, with the exception of being worded identically?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243851/213963)
- [How should we deal with questions that fit on more than one Stack Exchange site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61539/213963)
- [A bunch more linked questions on Meta.StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/64068?lq=1)

Comment: So, what is the correct way to handle an ***identical*** post across SE/SO sites?  ie., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48840903/8112776) and [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/271771/110651) ...?  Should I flag a mod?  Or is this case okay?  (I answered one, kinda want to copy/paste my answer to the other.  That must be okay if the duplicate question is okay...)